# Secure function evaluation for Boolean formulae

Tags: multiparty-computation

*Under the assumption* that "secure" encryption exists, secure evaluation of functions represented by Boolean circuits is possible by  [Yao's garbling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbled_circuit) scheme [Y1]. My question is whether secure evaluation of functions represented by Boolean *formulae* is an easier problem (i.e., possible in the information theoretic setting).

(This is true, for example for [secret sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing): Benaloh and Lichter [BL] gave an perfect scheme for access structures described by monotone Boolean formulae, but for monotone Boolean circuits one needs to assume secure encryption [Y2].)

References:

[[BL]](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/0-387-34799-2_3): Benaloh and Lichter. *Generalized secret sharing and monotone functions.* Crypto’88

[[Y1]](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1382944): Yao. *How to generate and exchange secrets.* FOCS’86.

[[Y2]](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/areas/sec/Yao1982.pdf): Yao. *Protocols for secure computations.* FOCS'82

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For log-depth circuits, it is possible to use an information-theoretic version of Yao's garbled circuits. Note that in a garbled gate, each key is used to encrypt twice. Thus, if the keys on the input wires are double the length of the keys on the output wires, then one-time pad encryption can be used and the result is information theoretically secure.

See the paper [Gate Evaluation Secret Sharing and Secure One-Round Two-Party Computation](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F11593447_8.pdf) by Vlad Kolesnikov, and references within.